# Make table row clickable to get controller action using javascript and mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to make a table row clickable using javascript. I have a table with customers and when the row is clicked, it should forward to the detals view. But now im stuck with the javascript. First of all I cant seem to get the id of the row.. and second it dosent seem to call the Details method in the Customer controller...
my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#customers tr').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).id;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Details","Customer")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { id: id }
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the id you need to do:

```
var id = $(this).attr( 'id' );
```

not sure about the other part, can you view the source in browser and verify the url?